# CSS fixed position on X axis but absolute on Y axis?

Tags: css, position, fixed

My container, `#topmenu` is in fixed position. I just added a phone number (image) that I want to move with this bar, but it doesn't move with the fixed bar.

I've absolutely positioned it within a relatively positioned element, but it just doesn't stick.

If I just make the phone number position:fixed then it moves around with the viewport width. What's the best way to accomplish what I'm doing?

CSS fragment:

```css
.topsocial a { margin-left: 15px;  }
#topmenu {position:fixed; z-index:220; }
#topmenu .ktwrap {padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; color: #fff;}
#topmenu ul li { display:inline; list-style-type: none; padding: 0px 10px 0 0; font-size: 13px; }
#topmenu .widget-container { margin-top: 5px;}
.topsocial .widget-containter {margin-top: 0px!important;}

#menu-menu li a span {
    display:block;
    line-height:14px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-transform: lowercase!important;
}       

.menu-menu ul li a span {
    line-height:14px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-transform: lowercase!important;
}

.topsocial {margin-top: 5px; color: #fff;}

.ktlogo {float: left; width: auto; margin-top:-35px; margin-left: 137px; font-family: 'HoneyScriptLight'; font-size: 60px; padding-top: 22px; }

.ktlogo img:hover {background: none;}

#navigationtop { font-size: 12px; color: #fff;}
#navigationtop ul li strong { display: block; padding-bottom: 7px; font-size: 14px; }
#navigationtop .ktwrap { padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 5px; height:71px; }
#floatnumber {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: 150px;
    z-index : 270;  
}
```

PHP fragment:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'includes/template-parts/topbar' ); ?>

<?php } ?>

<?php 
$disable_sidebar = of_get_option('disable_footer', '' );
if( $disable_sidebar['navbar']==0 ) { ?>

<div class="ktfullwidth" id="navigationtop"> 
    <div class="ktwrap"> <div id="floatnumber"><img src="http://combined-effort.com/wp-content/uploads/telephone-18005174660.png" alt="Phone Number 1-800-517-4660"></div>
        <div class="ktlogo">
            <?php 
            $disable_sidebar = of_get_option('disable_parts', '' );
            if( $disable_sidebar['logo']==0 ) { ?>

                <?php if ( of_get_option('logo') ) { ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>"><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('logo'); ?>" /></a>

                        <?php } else { ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>">

                        <?php if ( of_get_option('logotext') ) { ?>
                            <?php echo of_get_option('logotext', ''); ?></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        Combined Effort</a>
                        <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: The problem is on the client, so why are you showing the PHP code instead of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">...</ul>
<div class="topsocial right">...</div>
```

into

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">...</ul>
<div class="right">
  <img src="http://combined-effort.com/wp-content/uploads/telephone-18005174660.png" alt="Phone Number 1-800-517-4660">
  <div class="topsocial right">...</div>
</div>
```

And then delete the othe image.

Answer (score 0):

Without having read or tested your code in detail: If I got you right and you want to move the number with the bar then you have to put it within this fixed header. In the orignal code you can see that there are two overlapping headers and the number is NOT in the one with position fixed. Which there is

```
<div id="topmenu" class="ktfullwidth">
```

but in (and in your code seemingly as well)

```
<div class="ktfullwidth" id="navigationtop">
```

Put the number inside the #topmenu-div.

You might also be able to use position fied on the number itself, but i would recommend ot put it in the div.

Edit: I got confused by the names of the navigation-divs. I hope I got it right now.